# How do I access native java in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

For example, I would like to do some manipulation and methods using the Math native java class.

How could I gain access to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call any public and static method of exposed beans to Freemarker. See a similar question [here](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/Calling-static-methods-td626105.html). Also see the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_53).